# QueryDsl BooleanExpression - nested field is NULL

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

I want to create a predicate with `QueryDSL` and I don't know why but some nested field is NULL:

```
BooleanExpression emailSender =  qFreight.message.account.user.id.eq(userId);
```

user is NULL.

`qFreight.message.account.user` gives me NPE error

And then in logs I have

```
.180 ERROR 7316 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] p.a.m.s.filter.JwtAuthorizationFilter    : Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Of course I have generated `QFreight`, `QMessage`, `QAccount`, `QUser`... Where can bet the problem? I don't have any idea

**UPDATE**

My entities (the question is how to set @QueryInit properly):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "freight")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Freight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @QueryInit("*")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email_account_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_account_to_message"))
    private Account account;

 
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(builderMethodName = "of")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`qFreight.message.account.user.id` is not a valid JPQL expression. You'd have to create the joins between the entities explicitly: `JOIN qFreight.message message JOIN message.account account JOIN account.user user`. In QueryDSL this would be: `.join(qFreight.message, QMessage.message).join(QMessage.message.account, QAccount.account).join(QAccount.account.user, QUser.user).where(QUser.user.id.eq(...))`.

Furthermore, the QueryDSL metamodel by default is only initialized one level deep. This is a performance decision. If you need the metamodel to be initialized deeper (even though usecases are rare, because JPQL lacks support for implicit joins), you have to use `@QueryInits`: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.4.0/reference/html_single/#d0e2265

Comment: How can I use JOIN in my BooleanExpression?

Comment: Thats not possible. The join needs to be applied to the query itself. You might want to look into the `blaze-persistence-querydsl` integration which does bring implicit joins, which will allow you to write `qFreight.message.account.user.id` (assuming you've set the proper `@QueryInits` for it ) : https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-integration

Comment: I installed blaze-persistence-integration-querydsl-expressions and added entities. Can you help me with @QueryInit? It doesn't work for me... So you mean that after installing blaze-persistence-integration-querydsl-expressions I can use qFreight.message.account.user.id.eq(userId);???